# Loop through cells and copy paste values according to if condition

Tags: vba, excel, loops, range

I want to loop through a range of cells and extract specific information. I am trying to copy paste the cell.offset(0,-2) of the cell (a range) in sheet("Tracker") in the next empty cell of column D in sheet("1") if the value of the cell is the same as the variable r.Value (a variable that is an input value that changes everytime, so it has to stay as a variable). SO, since I am having cell (range) you understand its a loop for all the cells in the column G of the sheet("Tracker"). It works so far but the only thing that it does is get the first cell offset and paste it in the cell d1 of the destination sheet, overwritting my header. I want it to paste it from cell D2(first empty cell) and do this for all cells that abide by the if condition. Any ideas? The code is provided below..

The code below is the revised one!

The problem with the dates is as shown above.. I want to be as it appears inside the cell, not on the top of the page.. [image]

```
Dim v As Range
    Set v = Sheets("1").Cells(Worksheets("1").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)
    With Sheets("Tracker")
    For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(2, "G"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    If cell.Value = r.Value Then
    Set v = v.Offset(1, 0)
    v = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
    End If
    Next cell
    End With
```

Comment: `For Each cell In Range(cells(2, "G"), .cells(.rows.count, "G").End(xlUp))`

Comment: still. it says that .cells(.rows has an error

Comment: Yeah, I am so used to explicitly defining the parent worksheet with a With ... End With that I threw the periods in by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid select; explicitly define the parent worksheet; look from the bottom up to find the last populated cell; define your range with a starting point and an ending point.

```
Dim v As Range
Set v = WORKSheets("1").Cells(WORKSheets("1").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)
with WORKSheets("Tracker")
    For Each cell In .Range(.cells(2, "G"), .cells(.rows.count, "G").End(xlUp))
        If Int(cell.Value2) = Int(r.Value2) Then
            Set v = v.Offset(1, 0)
            v = cell.Offset(0, -1).value
        end if
    Next cell
end with
```

Comment: well still, nothing changed... I want this macro to loop through cells of the column G of the sheets("Tracker") and if the value of the cell is equal to the value of the r.Value (variable that is inputed in a pop up window before the macro starts) then, I want the cell in column F of the same row to be copy pasted in the column D of the sheets("1"). And the same process for all the cells in the column G

Comment: I suppose this can be done with a vlookup too, but I dont know how to vlookup one value in multiple rows ..

Comment: See modification above. Remember that `1 <> "1"` so if you are using an input box make sure you are comparing text to text or numbers to numbers and not text-that-look-like-numbers to true numbers.

Comment: actually the input is a date which I checked is in date number and so is the content of the column G!

Comment: Treat the date from input and the .Value2 from cell as longs.

Comment: my problem is that the date in one column is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm . So , i changed it manually to dd/mm/yyyy and it worked. would you possibly know how to change it automatically and convert dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm to dd/mm/yyyy? the dates in such format are in column G of "tracker" sheet

Comment: CLng converts and rounds off so the time after noon could push it to the next day. Use `application.rounddown(cell.value2, 0)` or more simply `Int(cell.value2)`.

Comment: I just want to cut the hh:mm part and not even round up and complicate things.. like in a way select the first 10 spots of the cells (8 numbers and two /) and just keep those.. sorry for insisting but I didnt get the previous part and how to implement it!

Comment: A day in Excel (VBA or worksheet) is **1** for every day past 31-Dec-1899. Today is 42971. Time is a decimal portion of a day. Today at noon is 42971.5 and today at 06:00pm is 42971.75. All you want to do is strip the decimal portion of the datetime to end up with a date/long with no time. CLng round off so CLng(today at 06:00pm) would be 42972, not 42971 but Int doesn't so Int(today at 06:00pm) would be 42971.

Comment: a ok !! thats really helpful! so, in which part of the code should I include the Int(cell.value2) ?

Comment: See above for `Int(...)` implementation.

Comment: I am really sorry for being annoying but I add this line of code just below the line with the For each and it says incomplete statement ...

Comment: I cannot see your screen. Edit your original question to include your revised code.

Comment: I just saw the edited reply from you! its absolutely on spot ! thanks once again!!